# Passlib/Argon2 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an application that implements Passlib and the Argon2 password hash onto an AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the application deploys fine with the command

> $eb create

However, when I invoke the function that calls the hashing, I get an HTTP 500, and on examining the logs I see the following errors:

> cls._stub_requires_backend() File
>   "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py",
>   line 2221, in _stub_requires_backend cls.set_backend() File
>   "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py",
>   line 2123, in set_backend return owner.set_backend(name,
>   dryrun=dryrun) File
>   "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py",
>   line 2143, in set_backend raise default_error
>   passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: argon2: no backends available --
>   recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install argon2_cffi')

This implies that the argon2-cffi package is not installed but a pip freeze (and my requirements.txt) both report the following:

```
argon2-cffi==16.3.0 
certifi==2017.7.27.1 
cffi==1.11.0 
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7 
Flask==0.12.2 
idna==2.6 
itsdangerous==0.24 
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0 
passlib==1.7.1 
pycparser==2.18 
pycryptodome==3.4.7
PyJWT==1.5.3 
pymongo==3.5.1 
requests==2.18.4 
six==1.11.0 
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

Does AWS support Passlib? Or am I doing something wrong with my deployment?